# Removing duplicates from a List containing wrapper Objects

Tags: apex, list, set

I am trying to remove duplicates from a List of Custom Objects.

This is what I am doing:

```
Set<CustomObject> mySet = new Set<CustomObject>();
mySet.addAll(originalList); //OriginalList contains duplicate Custom Objects.
System.debug(mySet.size()); //This always prints the same size of the original list
```

I don't know what is wrong happening here, When I see the list of items using debug there are clearly two Objects with same details.

Anything am I missing??

Comment: [This](http://foobarforce.com/2013/09/10/sobject-secret-life-equality-sets-maps/) may help you understand what's going on.

Comment: @BarCotter , Thanks for the link. I ended up adding the implementation for equals and hashCode method and now it is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

The Ids of records of that CustomObject are different. So the values in the set are different(each record is unique) and that's why they are not de-duplicated. If you want to use the Set based approach, clone each record and add it to the Set.

Set mySet = new Set();

for(CustomObject co : originalList) {
    mySet.add(co.clone());
}

//Check the size

Comment: Just tried it and I am still seeing the same size.. Do you think I should provide implementation for equals and hashCode method for my Custom Object??